# SBO tables Relationship (AR INVOICE-INCOMING Payment)

Tags: sql, join, crystal-reports, sapb1

am making a query that bring Incoming Payments details  , that include payment means , details of payment means , and then some  UDFS from the related A/R invoice(s) , in addition to some UDF from an object that relate to a UDF in the AR INVOICE ,

now every time am running my query it show no result.

Am sure there is something I missing here or incorrect but so far couldn't find it .

if any one can help me with this i will be thankful

here is  the query :

```
SELECT T1.[baseAbs] AS INVOICENO, T0.[DocDate],t0.[trsfrdate],t0.[trsfrref], T0.[CardName],T0.[Doctotal],T4.[VoucherNum] ,
T0.[Comments], T1.[DocNum] AS PAYMENTNO, T2.[Phone1],
T0.[CashSum], T0.[CreditSum], T0.[CheckSum], T0.[TrsfrSum],
T3.[DueDate] AS CHECKDATE, T3.[CheckNum] AS CHECKNO, T3.[Details] AS MAYBEBANKNAME
, t5.[U_UnitCode],t5.[U_Type],t7.[WhsName],t7.[city] ,
t8.U_FloorNo
FROM ORCT T0  
inner JOIN RCT2 T1 ON T0.[DocEntry]  = T1.[DocNum]
inner JOIN OINV T5 ON T5.[docnum] =T1.[BaseAbs]
INNER JOIN RCT1 T3 ON T0.[DocNum] = T3.[DocNum]
INNER JOIN RCT3 T4 ON T0.[DocNum] = T4.[DocNum]
INNER JOIN OCRD T2 ON T0.[CardCode] = T2.[CardCode]
INNER JOIN INV1 T6 ON T5.[DocEntry] = T6.[DocEntry]
INNER JOIN OWHS T7 ON T6.[WhsCode] = T7.[WhsCode]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[@AUND] T8 ON T5.[U_UnitCode] = T8.[Code]
```

Comment: It is really difficult to answer as we don't know how the data is...may you can try using outer joins may be inner joins are filtering the data also check the primary key and foreign key relationships

Comment: are you sure the table `RCT2` has the column `baseAbs`?

Comment: @JustDoIt , well i had update the query relationships , and used fields after i had some more understanding of the tables relationships , and it works now  , thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's a few issues with your query, starting with the join from ORCT to RCT2.

I've created similar queries in the past, here's one which I know works, maybe you can use it to adjust yours. For one thing, you'll definitely need to adjust a lot of those inner joins to outer joins, as a lot of the relations between Payments and it's parent business objects (like Invoices) are very loose and may not always apply.

Note that the query below is looking specifically for Invoices in the RCT2 table (this is the "lines" section of the Incoming Payment object), hence the J002.InvType = 13 condition.

```
SELECT *
FROM [ORCT] J001
LEFT OUTER JOIN [RCT2] J002 ON J002.DocNum = J001.DocNum AND J002.InvType = 13
LEFT OUTER JOIN [OINV] J003 ON J003.DocEntry = J002.DocEntry
LEFT OUTER JOIN [OACT] J004 ON J004.AcctCode = J001.CashAcct      
LEFT OUTER JOIN [RCT1] J005 ON J005.DocNum = J001.DocNum
```

Answer (score 2):

the query is now working fine now , the problem was in inner join , it should been replaced to left join , 
here is the fixed one :

```
select T0.DocNum as 'Payment Number',T0.DocDate 'Payment Date',T0.CardCode,
T0.CardName 'Customer Name',T1.BankCode 'Bankcode',T3.BankName 'Bank Name', T2.Phone1 ,
T0.CreditSum,
T0.CashSum,
T0.TrsfrSum,
t0.CheckSum,
t1.CheckNum as 'Check Number',
t1.DueDate as 'check date',
t6.VoucherNum as 'Voucher Number',
t0.TrsfrRef as 'Transfer No',
t0.TrsfrDate AS 'Transfer Date',
ousr.USER_code as 'user code',
 T5.DocNum, t11.U_P_BuildingName as 'Building Name',
CASE when T5.DocNum is null then 'On Account' else 'Paid For Invoice' END AS 'Payment Status',
CASE when T5.DocStatus = 'O' then 'Open' else 'Closed' END AS ' Invoice Status',
T4.SumApplied as 'Amount Paid on Invoice',T9.U_FloorNo,T5.U_UnitCode,T5.U_Type,
t0.DocTotal as 'Payment Total',t5.DocTotal as'Invoice Total' , t8.City,
t0.Comments as'Remarks'
from ORCT T0
left join rct1 T1 on T0.DocNum=T1.DocNum
left join ocrd T2 on T2.CardCode=T0.CardCode
left outer join ODSC T3 on T3.BankCode=T0.BankCode
left join RCT2 T4 on T0.DocNum = T4.DocNum
left join RCT3 T6 on T0.DocNum = T6.DocNum
left join OINV T5 on T4.DocEntry = T5.DocEntry and T5.ObjType = T4.InvType
left join oitm t11 on t5.u_unitcode = t11.ItemCode
LEFT JOIN OWHS T8 ON T11.U_P_BuildingNum  = T8.WhsCode
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[@AUND] T9 ON T5.[U_UnitCode] = T9.[Code]
 INNER JOIN  OSLP T10  ON T5.[SlpCode] = T10.[SlpCode] 
inner join ousr on ousr.USERID = t0.usersign
where 
T4.InvType <> '14' and T0.[Canceled] = 'N'  and t0.docnum=200001
```